# PHP remove first value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove first value from array, if first value (first character and last character) match 'ae'. The program will prompt the user the array is empty when finish comparing.

But the program will stop removing first value, when array left 2 value.

Code:

```
<?php
$activepath = array('a,s,d,e','a,n,m,e','a,k,g,e','a,q,w,e'); 
$path = null;
for($x = 0 ; $x < count($activepath); $x++)
{
$path = explode(",", $activepath[$x]);
if($path[0].end($path) === "ae")
{
array_shift($activepath);
}
var_dump($activepath);
}
?>
```

Result:

```
C:\wamp64\www\asd\test.php:18:
array (size=3)
0 => string 'a,n,m,e' (length=7)
1 => string 'a,k,g,e' (length=7)
2 => string 'a,q,w,e' (length=7)

C:\wamp64\www\asd\test.php:18:
array (size=2)
0 => string 'a,k,g,e' (length=7)
1 => string 'a,q,w,e' (length=7)
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense..All the values start with a and end with e. Are we supposed to remove them all? Or only the first one? Also, why loop? Looping will eventually lead to removal of all values since every time the next element becomes the first element.

Answer (score 0):

you are both shifting the first element out of the array as well as incrementing the index you are using to look at the array.  instead of a for loop, use a while to continue checking until a flag is set, and set that flash to true when you find that the first element of the array does *not* match your condition.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing will never work as you are shift and incrementing the array at the same time. 
Do something like this to check:

```
<?php

$activepath = array('a,s,d,e', 'a,n,m,e', 'a,k,g,e', 'a,q,w,e');
$path = null;
$newarray = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < count($activepath); $x++) {
    $path = explode(",", $activepath[$x]);
    if ($path[0] . end($path) === "ae") {
        array_push($newarray, $activepath[$x]);
    }
    var_dump($activepath);
}
if(count($newarray) == count($activepath))
    echo "All the element have 'ae'";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you J Earls for your hint. i manage to solve it with your hint.

```
<?php
$activepath = array('a,s,d,e','a,n,m,e','a,k,g,e','a,q,w,e');
$path = null;
$x = 0;

while ($activepath != null)
{

$path = explode(",", $activepath[$x]);

if($path[0].end($path) === "ae")
{
array_shift($activepath); 
}

if($activepath == null)
{
echo 'active-path is empty';
}

var_dump($activepath);

if($activepath == null)
{
break;
}

}   
?>
```